# How to pull a unique_ptr off a priority_queue and maintain the ownership semantics

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr

I have a unique_ptr in a priority_queue and I want to remove it from that collection and put it on a deque while maintaining the ownership semantics of unique_ptr. But I can't find a way to pull it off the priority_queue without a compile error: "attempting to reference a deleted function". What's the right way to accomplish this?

```
struct MyStruct {
    int val = 2;

    MyStruct(const int val) : val(val) {}
};

void testDeque() {
    std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>> q1;
    q1.emplace(std::make_unique<MyStruct>(10));
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>> q2;
    q2.push_back(q1.top()); // <- compiler error "attempting to reference a deleted function"
    q2.push_back(std::move(q1.top())); // <- compiler error "attempting to reference a deleted function"
    q1.pop();
}
```

Comment: Seem like you are not supposed to do that, as [top() returns a const_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top).

Comment: This is 100% the duplicate suggested by @MateuszDrost, the accepted answer there is even the same as the most upvoted answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own heap. All the heap functions are already in the `<algorithm>` header for you.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>> q1;

auto push = [&q1](std::unique_ptr<MyStruct> p) {
    q1.push_back(std::move(p));
    std::push_heap(q1.begin(), q1.end());
};

auto pop = [&q1]() {
    std::pop_heap(q1.begin(), q1.end());
    auto result = std::move(q1.back());
    q1.pop_back();
    return result;
};

push(std::make_unique<MyStruct>(10));
std::deque<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>> q2;
q2.push_back(pop());
```

Comment: So are you saying that because of the way the interface to priority_queue is defined, it can't do what I'm trying to and I have to use something else?

Comment: @taotree: You could use `std::priority_queue`, but not directly with `std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>`. You could wrap it in another struct with a mutable member, for example. But I think making your own little priority queue class with the desired interface would be better in the long run, and trivial to implement. (just wrap the lambdas I provided up into a class).

Answer (score 0):

If `priority_queue::top` returned a non-const reference, the user could change the value of the element, breaking the `priority_queue` internal invariants that make it work. Citing [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> Working with a priority_queue is similar to managing a heap in some random access container, with the benefit of ***not being able to accidentally invalidate the heap***.

So, your `priority_queue` is in invalid state between `std::move(q1.top())` and `q1.pop()`: the pointer is null after the move, so it is actually the smallest element now, not the greatest, which violates the class invariants. While this might work in practice, it is generally bad to rely on implementation details rather than on the documented behavior.

You may write your own `priority_queue` based on the `std::heap*` functions from `<algorithm>`, as Benjamin Lindley suggests in his post, that allows to change the values stored. Alternatively, you can use some sorted container, like `std::set`, sacrificing the benefits of a heap.

Comment: He can just write his own `Compare` function where `null`s are the greatest elements.

Comment: @MateuszDrost For sure. Still, `priority_queue` has no way to get a non-const reference to it's top element, and doing a `const_cast` would still violate the class interface: it simply doesn't support changing the stored values.

Answer (score -1):

As `top` returns `const_reference` which cannot be moved you should `const_cast` it:

```
q2.push_back(std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>&>(q1.top())));
```

`move` left object in valid state, so following `q1.pop()` is completely safe.